# Auth0.SDK.AuthenticationCancelException in Windows Phone 8.0 project

Tags: c#, silverlight, authentication, windows-phone-8

I am using Auth0Client for Windows Phone 8.0 project. I have problem with Auth0.SDK.AuthenticationCancelException - beacuse it's crashing my application all the time I press back button just after clicking LoginFacebookTap button.

So when I load application I go to LoginView Page, and there is button which will call:

```
private async void LoginFacebookTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var result = await authorizationService.LoginAuth0(AuthorizationService.AuthorizationServiceType.Facebook, "", "");
    if (result == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("OK!");
    }
}
```

and this it my method LoginAuth0

```
public async Task<Boolean> LoginAuth0(AuthorizationServiceType type, string email, string password)
{
    if (NetworkService.IsNetworkAvailable())
    {
        try
        {
            Auth0User user;
            switch (type)
            {
                case AuthorizationServiceType.EmailAndPassword:
                    user = await auth0.LoginAsync(Constants.login_with_password_Auth0, email, password);
                    break;
                case AuthorizationServiceType.Email:
                    user = await auth0.LoginAsync(Constants.login_azure_Auth0);
                    break;
                case AuthorizationServiceType.Facebook:
                    user = await auth0.LoginAsync(Constants.login_facebook_Auth0);
                    break;
                case AuthorizationServiceType.Google:
                    user = await auth0.LoginAsync(Constants.login_google_Auth0);
                    break;
                case AuthorizationServiceType.Linkedin:
                    user = await auth0.LoginAsync(Constants.login_linkedin_Auth0);
                    break;
                case AuthorizationServiceType.Twitter:
                    user = await auth0.LoginAsync(Constants.login_twitter_Auth0);
                    break;
                case AuthorizationServiceType.Windows:
                    user = await auth0.LoginAsync(Constants.login_windows_Auth0);
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (AuthenticationCancelException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("User press cancel on Authentication");
            return false;
        }
        catch (AuthenticationErrorException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Resources.AppResources.TitleError + " : " + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Resources.AppResources.MessageErrorUserNotExists);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unknown exception: "+exc.Message);
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            var targetClientId = Constants.clientId_Auth0;
            var options = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "scope", "openid profile" }
            };
            var delegationResult = await auth0.GetDelegationToken(targetClientId, options);

            if (delegationResult != null)
            {
                String jsonString = delegationResult["id_token"].ToString();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Application received token: " + jsonString);
                return true;
            }
            else MessageBox.Show(AppResources.MessageErrorSigning);
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Resources.AppResources.TitleError +" : " + exc.Message);
        }
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Resources.AppResources.MessageErrorNoConnection);
        return false;
    }
}
```

and just after I click LoginFacebookTap and press Back button it will result as:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'Auth0.SDK.AuthenticationCancelException' occurred in
>   Auth0Client.Phone.Silverlight.ni.DLL A first chance exception of type
>   'Auth0.SDK.AuthenticationCancelException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
>   A first chance exception of type
>   'Auth0.SDK.AuthenticationCancelException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll

and then application just crash with "InvalidOperationException Cannot go back when CanGoBack is false.". It's bug or?

## Update

What I figure out is that it only occur when you log in into your facebook account and you are authenticated. Then when you again run application and click on LoginFacebookTap you won't be redirect into facebook login page, but you are automatically redirect back with 'OK' result of authentication. Before you are redirected back to LoginView you see white screen and when you press Back you will return with "InvalidOperationException Cannot go back when CanGoBack is false."

## Update 2

What I figure out in Auth0.SDK:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handler for the browser control's navigation failed event.  We use this to detect errors
/// </summary>
private void BrowserControl_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowserNavigationException navEx = e.Exception as WebBrowserNavigationException;

    if (navEx != null)
    {
        // Pass along the provided error information.
        responseErrorDetail = string.Format("Error code: {0}", navEx.StatusCode);
    }
    else
    {
        // No error information available.
        responseErrorDetail = NoDetailsAvailableMessage;
    }
    responseStatus = PhoneAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp;

    authenticationFinished = true;
    e.Handled = true;

    // Navigate back now.
    this.NavigateBackWithProgress();
}

/// <summary>
/// Displays the progress bar and navigates to the previous page.
/// </summary>
private void NavigateBackWithProgress()
{
    ShowProgressBar();
    NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```

At NavigationService.GoBack(); we have InvalidOperationException Cannot go back when CanGoBack is false.

Comment: So are you saying that the try/catch is not working?

Comment: No. I am saying that I have no idea where did that come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bug on SDK:

```
private void NavigateBackWithProgress()
 {
     ShowProgressBar();
    if(NavigationService.CanGoBack)
        NavigationService.GoBack();
 }
```

Before invoking NavigationService.GoBack() we should always check if there are even pages on the back stack. It also refer to:

```
private void NavigateBackWithProgress()
 {
     ShowProgressBar();
    if(this.Frame != null && this.Frame.CanGoBack)
        this.Frame.GoBack();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the SDK throws an exception when you cancel the authentication. You are catching it, so that's ok

Comment: Not really. It's not exception that throws SDK but it's exception because before invoking NavigationService.GoBack() we should always check if there are even pages on the back stack.

I clone SDK and add if(NavigationService.CanGoBack) check.